# Typing rule for corresponding `val` and `let` bindings

Tags: type-theory, pl.programming-languages

$\newcommand{\clet}{\texttt{let }}
\newcommand{\cval}{\texttt{val }}
\newcommand{\cin}{\texttt{ in }}
$I have the syntax for a programming language containing both let-bindings of the form $\clet x = e_1 \cin e_2$ and val-bindings of the form $\cval x : t \cin e$.

I'd like to enforce that a `val`-binding is only well-formed
if $e$ contains a corresponding `let`-binding. My first thought was to use a typing rule like

$$
\dfrac{\Gamma, \;\;\cval x : t \cin e \quad x \in BV(e)}
{\Gamma \vdash x : t} \quad\textsf{wf-val}
$$

but that doesn't enforce that $x$ appear in a `let`-binding - only as a variable that may be unbound, in which case the rule doesn't really work.

What would be the most idiomatic way to express this? One thing I considered was testing if a term of the form $\clet x = \dots$ appears as a subterm of $e$, though ideally the rule would enforce that the matching `let` appears at the same level as the `val` (i.e. not in the body of a lambda).

Comment: What is `val` supposed to be, intuitively speaking? An un-initialized variable? The rule wf-val is very odd. Is it turned upside down? What is happening with $e$ in that rule?

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear, `val` is basically a replacement for an explicit annotation term like `x: t`. The name comes the `val` keyword in OCaml which you use to give the type of an expression. I want to enforce that each type declaration with `val` actually accompanies a term but I'm not sure how to express it. That's not really a problem with `: t` syntax since the term being typed is part of the expression

Comment: Ocaml `val` is *never* combined with expressions, it is always part of the *signature*. The concept you are looking for is *type ascription*, and it works for any expression, not just variables. In any case, the type of a variable should be introduced at the point where the variable is introduced, not in a random place before that.

Answer (score 0):

Ocaml `val` is never used in expressions, only in signatures. If your intent is to prescribe the type of a newly introduced variable, then you should do it when the variable is introduced, i.e., in `let`-binding:
$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash e_1 : A \qquad \Gamma, x : A \vdash e_2 : B}
  {\Gamma \vdash (\mathsf{let}\, x : A = e_1 \;\mathsf{in} e_2) : B}
$$
An example in OCaml:

```
# let x : int list = [] ;;
val x : int list = []
```

(Without the annotation, OCaml would answer that the type of `x` is `'a list`.)

A related concept is *type ascription*, which prescribes the type of an expressions (not necessarily a variable):
$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash e : A \qquad \Gamma \vdash A = B}
  {\Gamma \vdash (e : A) : B}
$$
An example in OCaml:

```
# fun x -> ((x, x) : int * int) ;;
- : int -> int * int = <fun>
```

(Without the ascription, Ocaml would infer the type `'a -> 'a * 'a`.)

Just don't try to mix `val` and `let`.